# JavaScript is Preceding Operation Before Clicking the "Submit" Button/Link

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to JavaScript, and I am having a little difficulty getting my operation to perform correctly.  The program is running my code before I click on my submit button.  There are many similar questions that have been covered so far, but I don't believe any of them have covered this exact issue.  Please refrain from flagging this as answered elsewhere (believe me, I read those documents).  Thanks in advance for the help.

```
<html>
<body style="background-color: lightgrey">
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='newcss.css'/>
<ol>
    <p style="color:black">Scan Location</p>
</ol>

<table class="scanLocation" align="center">
       <tr>
           <td>
               <ol>
                    <input type="text" name="fname" maxlength= "18" size= "33" input style="font-size:20px"/>

               </ol>
           </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <td>
               <ol>
                   <form>
                        <input type="button" onclick="script" value="Submit"/>
                            <p id="seconds"></p>
                                <script>
                                    firstFunction();
                                    function firstFunction(){
                                    var date = new Date();
                                    var seconds = date.getUTCSeconds();
                                        myFunction();
                                        function myFunction(){
                                        document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML = "seconds";
                                        }
                                        checkEven();
                                        function checkEven(seconds){
                                        return Math.floor(seconds%2) == Math.floor(0);
                                        }
                                        if(checkEven(seconds)){
                                            location.href='index2.jsp';
                                        }
                                        else{
                                            location.href='index3.jsp';
                                        }
                                        }
                                </script>
                   </form>
               </ol>
           </td>
       </tr>
</table>
</body>
<script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Is this the exact code that you have problems with? You are not binding anything to the submit of your form, or the click of your button. You are just calling the function `firstFunction();` right before you declare it (which is bad anyway, it could cause a race condition where the function is called before it is known). Also, that script block belongs on the bottom of your page, not inside your form.

Comment: Thank you.  I'm sorry, I had that and posted the wrong script (silly me).  I must have deleted the wrong code.  Anyway, you solved my problem.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should look more like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='newcss.css'/>
</head>
<body style="background-color: lightgrey">
<ol>
    <p style="color:black">Scan Location</p>
</ol>
<form onsubmit="firstFunction()">
<table class="scanLocation" align="center">
       <tr>
           <td>
               <ol>
                    <input type="text" name="fname" maxlength= "18" size= "33" input style="font-size:20px"/>

               </ol>
           </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <td>
               <ol>
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
                    <p id="seconds"></p>                                
               </ol>
           </td>
       </tr>
</table>
</form>

<script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>
<script>
function firstFunction(){
  /* your logic here */
}                                  
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

What I did:

- I placed the form tags around the table, as I suspect you want that `fname` field to be part of your form as well, not just the button.
- I moved the script block to the bottom of your `body` (not outside the body), after the load of the external script (judging from your logic there are some functions in there that need to be loaded for the 'firstFunction' to work
- added an `onsubmit` to your form. This is better then binding to the button, since there are more ways to submit a form then just by clicking the submit button (return key ie.). I changed the button type to `submit` for the same reason.
- I removed the function call `firstFunction()` just above the declaration of the function. You do not want to call the function yet, as it only needs to be triggered o submit. Also, you'ld better declare the function **before** you call it to prevent a race condition.
- I fixed te link to your stylesheet, by moving it into the head section of your page. According to the specs it is the only place where linked stylesheets are allowed. Your way will probably work in most browsers, but it's better to do it the right way.

Comment: Hey, thank you so much for the help!  This is a fantastic response, and it is soooo helpful for a person just learning a new coding language.  Keep up the awesome work!

Answer (score 0):

The script is executed exactly as you've written it. The problem is that you didn't specify onclick event correctly, the right version is:

```
<input type="button" onclick="firstFunction()" value="Submit"/>
```

And you should remove function call from the script itself, I mean this line right after opening script tag:

```
firstFunction();
```

In general it isn't the best option to bind an event as you HTML which should be just a presentation is dealing with the behavior as well, in a complex project it will be a pain to manage such pages but perhaps for the sake of studying it's fine.

Comment: Awesome help, man.  thank you very much for helping me out.  I accidentally posted the wrong script, but you helped me figure out what was actually preventing my code from working.  Thank you so much for the help!